# Galois Field Matrix Multiplication for 512 bit number

Tags: finite-fields, galois-extensions

I am a beginner in the filed theory. So, I have a few questions.

1. Consider a matrix $A$ whose each element is in $GF(2)$ (i.e. $0$ or $1$) and a matrix $B$, each element of which is of $512$ bits. If I multiply them together, $C = AB$, will the elements of $C$ be of $512$ bits, or just $0$ and $1$?
2. Similarly, if we consider the elements of $A$ is in $GF(2^{10})$, what would be the elements of $C$?

I am a bit confused. I think for the first question the answer should be $512$ bits and for the second question, the answer should also be the same. Can someone clarify if I am right or not?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't think we can answer your question as it stands. You need to tell us where $A$ and $B$ come from, and what you want to use $C$ for.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant by where $A$ and $B$ come from? Let me give you an example. If $A$ = [$1$ $0$;$1$ $1$] and $B$ is $[5;3]$ then you can have $C$ as $[5;8]$. Here we can express 5, 3 and 8 in binary. If we consider them as 3 bits, result is also 3 bits. So, my question was does it change for $GF(2)$ or $GF(2^{10})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English languages uses 26 alphabets. But when we read it we have to read them word by word (rather than individual letters).  Analogously all Galois Fields $GF(2^n)$ for all $n$ use binary digits 0 and 1 at a primitive level. But words here are "n-bits at a time".   So Galois Fields $GF(512)$ and $GF(1024)$ are to be understood as using same alphabet but their word lengths are 9 and 10 respectively.

The theory tells us  how to add two $n$-bit string to fetch an $n$-bit string as their sum (bitwise XOR). And also the mathematicians have a rule (somewhat complicated) that specifies how to multiply two $n$-bit strings to yield another $n$-bit string as their product. The "sum" and "product" operations  on binary strings obeying the usual conditions of our familiar number system (commutativity, assocoitivity, distributivity etc).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for second case, we can do simple matrix multiplication and then use irreducible polynomial to find the mod. Then replace each value with this mod. But if I use this same logic for the first case, doesn't it simply reduce it to 1 and 0?

Comment: When you do matrix multiplication entry at  position (i,j) is: $x_{i1}.y_{1j}+x_{i2}.y_{2j}+\cdots+x_{in}.y_{nj}$     Each entry such as $x_{ik}$ is a 9-bit string. The dot means the multiplication of, e.g., 9-bit strings I mentioned. The plus sign means bitwise XOR. So it WILL reduce to a word of 9-bit string. This is your case 2. For your case 1, each product $x_{ik}y_{kj}$ will be either 0 or 1. So  finally it will be 1 if and only odd number of such products are 1.

Comment: I think I understand what your are saying. Thanks!

Comment: So, is it not possible to have multiplication of  two matrices while elements of one are in $GF(2)$ and other is in $R$ to result in a matrix in $R$?

Comment: NO. Nit because some impossibility result. All the existing binary operations take two elements BOTH from same set, and yield an answer  in the same set.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help!